# how to remove --------- from django Select widgets

Tags: django, forms, widget

How do I remove the ----- in my django ModelForm widgts?
documentation say to use empty_label but it is for SelectDateWidget

my form

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ('copy', 'created', 'researcher', 'keywords', 'application_area', 'predominant_area')

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class':'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Titulo da oportunidade'
            }),
            'conclusion_date':forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'type':'text',
                'placeholder':'Data de conclusão'
        }),
            'category': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
                'class':'form-control'
        }),
            'result':forms.Select(attrs={
                'class':'form-control'
        }),
     }
```

Comment: you can add default value

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  Do you have any tutorial that I can follow ?

Comment: is my answer worked?

Comment: yes it did man , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add default value for your select input then it will show default value initially.

For further reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/